# The most elegant way to write an abstraction layer

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm curious how to write an abstraction layer.
By abstraction layer, I mean a wrapper above one or more 3rd party libraries.

Or do I have to solve it like this?

```
#include<an3rdpartyl>
#include<another3rdpartyl>

class layer
{
private:
    an3rdpartyl* object1;
    another3rdpartyl* object2;
public:
    //...
    int loadModel(char* file)
    {
        return object2->LoadMeshFromFile(file);
    }
    //...
};
```

Comment: What's the question? Why `loadModel()` is using `object2` and not `object1`? (Also, would you mind indenting your code please?)

Comment: Just to write that in a more unelegant way.

Comment: It's "inelegant", if you wanted to use the antonym of "elegant" :-) http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inelegant

Comment: Sorry, english is not my native language.
Anyway thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), and [Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) patterns. Or even better, just pick up the "Gang of Four" [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) book and learn about software design in a whole new light.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look up the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: How is Decorator relevant to his question? Decorator is for adding behavior at *runtime*.